# Why is Panda's read_excel producing unworkable DataFrame with the wrong number of columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm probably missing something basic here, but I've been having some serious trouble using pd.read_excel and pd.read_csv. Was struggling with a couple files for a while, then tried it with a super basic table just to test and I'm hitting the same issues:

1. When I use df.shape, it always shows 14 columns. Some of the files have more, some have less, none of them have 14.
2. Even though the type shows as pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, nothing else works. I can't even see the head of the df. It always gives me an "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'"

my test file is called 'test.xlsx', and is just this:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 9 |10 |11 |12 |
```

I use `test = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')` to bring it in and it seems to work fine.

`type(test)` returns "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"

`test.shape` returns "(3, 14)". Why 14? I don't know. Even when I use `usecols=...` it always returns 14.

`test.head()` returns an AttributeError, which I'll paste in full below.

What is going on??

Thank you for your help in advance, and remember: Folks who are patient with novices are the best kind of folks :)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    400                         if cls is not object \
    401                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 402                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    403 
    404             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    695     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    696     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 697     output = repr(obj)
    698     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    699         if idx:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __repr__(self)
     76         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
...
-> 1438         return index.name is not None
   1439 
   1440 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    672 
    673             return self.to_html(max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 674                                 show_dimensions=show_dimensions, notebook=True)
    675         else:
    676             return None

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_html(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, bold_rows, classes, escape, notebook, border, table_id, render_links)
   2263                                            render_links=render_links)
   2264         # TODO: a generic formatter wld b in DataFrameFormatter
-> 2265         formatter.to_html(classes=classes, notebook=notebook, border=border)
   2266 
   2267         if buf is None:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_html(self, classes, notebook, border)
    727         from pandas.io.formats.html import HTMLFormatter, NotebookFormatter
...
--> 293                     row.append(self.columns.name or '')
    294                 else:
    295                     row.append('')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: tried your exact table and import with pandas gives shape 3,4 as expected

Comment: 1) Open your excel file. 2) Click Save. 3) Close your Excel file. 4) Try `pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')` again. Do you get different results?

Comment: Closed everything, resaved, reopened and all works as expected. Thanks @BeRT2me and Chris for your responses. I feel like an idiot, but I'm glad it's finally working. ...I shudder to think how many hours I wasted yesterday...